# Setting up Jetty as a service

Tags: java, linux, configuration, jetty

I've finally managed to get Jetty7 running as a service in Debian.

Still, I'm unsure if I made the right steps or didn't forget something.

So far, I've done the following:

1. Untared the downloaded tar file to `/opt/jetty-distribution-$JETTY_VERSION`
2. Created a softlink `` `/opt/jetty `` pointing to `/opt/jetty-distribution-$JETTY_VERSION`
3. Copied the `jetty.sh` file (found in `/opt/bin/jetty.etc` to `/etc/init.d`
4. Uncommented the three lines (like the comments in the `sh` file say)

Is this okay? I didn't set `$JETTY_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME`, `JAVA` explicitely, as Jetty seems to be able to figure them out.

Comment: Have you tried running it from init.d? like sudo ./jetty.sh start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about Debian but in SUSE/Redhat you'd have to actually add that to your runlevels

chkconfig --add jetty.sh

and there are some header lines you should have at the beginning of jetty.sh (take a look at other /etc/init.d stuff for example)